# Week and month sort

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to add two columns to my financial calendar on SQL server that will sort the weeks and months according to an assigned integer. The update statement needs to have some sort of an increment only on the weeks and months.
The result should be like this:

```
 Weeks|Months|Week_Sort|Month_Sort
2017_1|2017_4|        1|         1
2017_2|2017_4|        2|         1
```

Please assist.Bear in mind the weeks go back to 2014 up until 2017 so i cant manually add them.

Comment: So you have Weeks from 2014_1 to 2014_52, then 2015_01 to 2015_52 and so on? and months? 2014_01 to 2014_12 and so on?

Comment: What is the logic behind adding those 2 columns?

Comment: On PowerBi i use them to sort my visuals according to weeks since powerbi and sql sort the weeks like 2017_1, 2017_10, etc so i want to eliminate that

Answer (score 0):

Use dense_rank

```
select weeks, months,
       dense_rank() over (order by weeks) as week_sort,
       dense_rank() over (order by months) as month_sort
from MyTable
```

Comment: Thanks i worked but now when I apply it reads the weeks as 2017_1, 2017_10, 2017_11, 2017_12, 2017_13, 2017_14, 2017_15, 2017_16, 2017_17, 2018_18, 2018_19, 2017_2, 2017_20, 2017_21 etc so it added those increment numbers in that order too. Is there way around this?